# JTextArea is not getting added to frame

Tags: java, swing

I am unable to understand why JTextArea is not getting displayed with my code.
This is the first time i am using FocusAdapter class in a swing program.

Here is the code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Focus extends FocusAdapter
{
    JFrame f;
    JTextArea jt;
    Focus()
    {
        f=new JFrame("focus");
        jt=new JTextArea(50,50);
        jt.addFocusListener(this);
        jt.setFont(new Font("varinda",Font.PLAIN,15));

        f.setSize(550,550);
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe)
    {
        jt.setText("focusgained");
    }
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        new Focus();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you add the text area to the frame? `This is the first time i am using FocusAdapter` - a FocusAdapter has nothing to do with displaying a JTextArea. Learn one step at a time? 1) Create a JFrame and add a JTextArea to it. 2) Then try adding a FocusListener to the text area. Also, don't use a null layout. The text area will not display when you use a null layout. Use layout managers. Read the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for some Swing basics. Maybe start with `How to Use Text Areas` then `How to Write a FocusListner`.

Comment: I forgot to add JTextArea to frame. Now its working.

Answer (score 2):

> am unable to understand why JTextArea is not getting displayed with my code. This is the first time i am using FocusAdapter class in a swing program.

It was because you set the layout of the JFrame to null and I don't see you adding the JTextField to your JFrame.

You may do this:

```
f.add(jt);
jt.setBounds(x, y, width, height); //Give int values for x, y, width, height
```

Last but not least, try to use a layout for your JFrame and you can consider adding a JPanel to the JFrame instead of adding components directly into the JFrame.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

The basic answer to you question is, you need to actually add the `JTextArea` to displable container, in this, your `JFrame`, for example...

```
public class Focus extends FocusAdapter
{
    JFrame f;
    JTextArea jt;
    Focus()
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }


                jt=new JTextArea(50,50);
                jt.addFocusListener(this);
                jt.setFont(new Font("varinda",Font.PLAIN,15));

                f = new JFrame("Testing");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.add(new JScrollPane(jt));
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe)
    {
        jt.setText("focusgained");
    }
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        new Focus();
    }
}
```

Have a look at

- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)
- [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

for more details

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the JTextArea to your JFrame. This is why it' not added. ;)

You can do so by:

```
f.add(jt);
f.setSize(500,500);
```

or:

```
f.add(new JScrollPane(jt) );
```